# What are the tax implications of transfer fees while rolling over Roth IRA held in CD?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, certificate-of-deposit

I have some money in a CD that's in a Roth IRA account. I'd like to transfer it out of that account and into another one, as part of a roll over. The CD is not at maturity, so I will need to pay a termination fee. What are the tax implications of me paying money to terminate the CD?

Comment: Can you pay the fee out of the CD balance?

Comment: _You_ cannot pay cash money to your IRA custodian to terminate the CD early; the early termination fee merely reduces the amount that gets rolled over into your new IRA account. If and when in the far-distant future, you have withdrawn _all the money_ from _all_ of your Roth IRA accounts, and it turns out that the total amount withdrawn is _less_ than the total amount _contributed or rolled over_ into your Roth IRA, then the net loss can be deducted as a Miscellaneous Deduction on Schedule A, subject of course to the 2% floor for Miscellaneous Deductions (i.e. no deduction for most folks.)